# 60/5 A CT Burden Resistance

Tags: current, transformer

I am using a CT 60/5 A. I would like to know how would I select a burden resistance to convert 5A current to 400mV signal? I understand that V=IR will give the required resistance, however, for 5A even 1ohm resistance will develop 5V and hence the power dissipation of resistance has to be atleast 25W(P = V*V/R) which is huge. How should I calculate the resistance so that it remains in reasonable power dissipation level? What if the burden is rated at 1VA? Assume that the current in primary can reach close to 60A.

Comment: In link you will find about current measuring.  
http://www.mmgca.com/apps/MMG-ctdesign.pdf

Answer (score 3):

As you say, you can simply apply Ohm's law, which gives you 80m\$\Omega\$ for 400mV. The power dissipation at 5A secondary current will be 2W which is fairly reasonable, but it's pretty much irrelevant. The output current is *fixed* (so long as you stay within the acceptable range for the particular CT) so if you want V volts the resistance *cannot* vary from that number.

Of course you are free to use a lower value resistance (say 20m\$\Omega\$) which would give you 100mV and only dissipate 0.5W maximum, but would only give 100mV RMS full scale, so you might need an amplifier. The use of a 4-wire (Kelvin) connection becomes even more important at such low resistances as only 200\$\mu\Omega\$ in the wrong place will represent a relatively large 1% error.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the lowest resistance available in local market is 2.2ohm. I may connect five such resistances with 3   Watt rating to be on safer side and then use a voltage divider to get desired voltage but doesn't it make an amateur design? I have across some control modules of generators and have not seen resistances connected in parallel at the CT interface.

Comment: Wind your own with some wire.. Even copper has resistance, 10 Feet of 20 AWG copper has a resistance of 0.101 Ohms as a baseline.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand what the specifications mean (fortunately :-) )
Your error is in assuming that Iprimary flows in the burden resistor.
The burden resistor is connected across the secondary - NOT the primary.
Isecondary is N times smaller than I_primary where N is the turns ratio of the CT.  So power dissipation is FAR lower than you have calculated.

A CT has a 1 turn (usually) primary and an N turn secondary.
Current in the primary and (critical here) current in the secondary is N times lower.
Voltage in the secondary is set by the burden resistor - usually selected to be  in the 100 mV - 10V range, and voltage in the primary is N times lower.

So eg for a 5A full scale CT with 400 mV output and a say 1:100 turns ratio.
Iprimary = 5A.
I secondary = 5A/N = 5A/100 = 50 mA
V secondary = 400 mV
Vprimary = 400 mV/N =- 400 mV/100 = 4 mV

POWER in burden resistor = Isecondary x Vsecondary
= 0.050 A x 400 mV = 20 mW.
R burden = V/I = Vsecondary / I secondary = 0.400 / 0.050 = 8 Ohms.